# Azure Servicebus, MassTransit and DLQ's. Moving from DLQ to original queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

It really annoys me that we're unable to move messages from a `Dead Letter Queue` over to the `Original Queue` for processing when using Azure Servicebus. So, I figured out that I will try to implement this feature myself. We are using `Masstransit` to publish events. The queuename in ASB will be an events full assembly name.

I've created an `REST Endpoint` in my application to move messages from the DLQ to the original queue for reprocessing. This is where I'm stuck at the moment.

To get all messages in a DLQ, the user gives me the queuename, and I will format it to contain the DeadLetterQueue. Like this:

```
myproject.events.usercreatedevent -> myproject.events.usercreatedevent/$DeadLetterQueue
```

I get all the messages from this queue by using classes from the Nuget package [Microsoft.Azure.Servicebus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/)

```
public async Task RequeueMessagesAsync(string queueName)
{
    var msg = new MessageReceiver(BuildConnectionString(), queueName);
    var messages = await msg.PeekAsync(50);

    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(content);
        var destinationAddress = jsonObject["destinationAddress"].ToString();
        var messageContent = jsonObject["message"].ToString();
        var messageType = destinationAddress.Split("/").Last();

        await _bus.SendAsync(jsonObject, messageType);
    }
}
```

The when calling `_bus.SendAsync(object, address)` the message ends up in a `_skipped queue`. I think the reason for this is that the `messageHeaders` is set to `JObject`, and not the actual message type. I cannot use reflection to recreated the event either, as we have a lot of microservices and source code of the event it not necessarily available. The code behind the `_bus.SendAsync(object, address)` looks like this:

```
public async Task SendAsync(object message, string queueName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ISendEndpoint sender = await GetSenderAsync(queueName); 
    sender.ConnectSendObserver(new ErrorQueueConfiguration(_addressProvider.GetAddress("error")));

    await sender.Send(message, cancellationToken);
}
```

Can I trick Masstransit to forward this "unknown" type to my Consumer by changing the MessageHeaders somehow? Have anyone successfully moved messages from a DLQ to its original queue?

Comment: I typically use ServiceBusExplorer to move messages from DLQ->Queue, without changing the message body at all.

Comment: It would be quite annoying to create your custom solution if you are using considering some out of the box solution, then you got to check out Serverless360 where you can Repair and Resubmit the messages out of the box.

Comment: @NadeemAhamed Thanks for the info. I find it annoying that Microsoft hasn't implemented this solution in ASB. I've previously worked with rabbitmq and from that management portal you have the option to shovel messages back to its original queue. As I'm using macOS I cannot run ServiceBusExplorer unless I do so in a virtualized environment.

Comment: Try checking out Serverless360 as well where you have SaaS version, so no need to worry about OS.